# Sql server issue after installing VS 2012 - SQL Server Agent gives- Remote procedure call failed (0x800706be)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I have recently installed VS 2012, after installing i am not able to see SQL serve services under configuration manager- it is giving error message - Remote procedure call failed (0x800706be). I tried googling for solution but didn't get any proper answer or workaround for this issue. My OS is Win7 home premium.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other SQL Database like SQL Server 2008 or older in your computer before you install the Visual Studio 2012?

This issue happened because maybe you have SQL Server 2012 Express along side older versions like SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.

To solve the problem, try to re-install your Visual Studio and do not add the SQL Express.

Another workaround is you install a patch with the latest service pack for your older SQL.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error after I have installed the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 setup in my work machine.

Since it is being a WMI error, I recompiled the MOF file –> mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

I also un-registered and re-registered the sql provider DLL –> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmprovider.dll" but issue not resolved.

**Solution**:

I have applied SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 on my SQL 2008 R2 instance and that fixed the issue with Sql Server Configuration Manager. You can download setup from here... http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437 .

Answer (score -1):

You have to Remove the Old Sql Server and Reinstall Sql Server if you want to backup your data your can backup from C:/ Sql Server Directory and after that it will work fine...

Watch this video how to install Visual Studio 2012 and Sql Server 2012 in windows 7

**Visual Studio 2012 Installation**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LnyH-evqeY

**Sql Server 2012 Installation**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTVLo9kvK3w